# How to convert QList<QByteArray> to QString in QT?

Tags: qt

I have a `QList<QByteArray>` that I want to print out in a `QTextBrowser`. QTextBrowser->append() takes a QString.

Despite a ton of searching online, I have not found a way to convert the data I have into a QString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); ++i){
    QString str(list[i].constData());
    // use your string as needed
}
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the encoding of data in `QByteArray`. Frank Osterfeld's answer is better.

Comment: Frank didn't address the QList part of the question, which was actually what was causing me trouble.

Answer (score 6):

There are several functions to convert QByteArray to QString: QString::fromAscii(), QString::fromLatin1(), QString::fromUtf8() etc. for the most common ones, and QTextCodec for other encodings. Which one is the correct one depends on the encoding of the text data in the byte array.

Answer (score 0):

from `QByteArray` to `QString`, do

```
const char * QByteArray::constData () const
```

> Returns a pointer to the data stored in the byte array. The pointer
>   can be used to access the bytes that compose the array. The data is
>   '\0'-terminated. The pointer remains valid as long as the byte array
>   isn't reallocated or destroyed.
>
> This function is mostly useful to pass a byte array to a function that
>   accepts a const char *.

you then have this `QString` constructor

```
QString ( const QChar * unicode )
```